# Is it possible to chain  array.push() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 separate arrays and I'm looking to load them all into to a single array. Am I able to use `.push()` several arrays into one? Is something like this possible?

```
 var activeMembers=[];      // Active Users
 var noactiveMsg=[];        // Non-Active Users with a Pending Message
 var noactiveNomsg=[];      // Non-Active Users without a Pending Message
 var chatCenterMembers=[];          // Final Array of Chat Center Members


 chatCenterMembers.push(activeMembers).push(noactiveMsg).push(noactiveNomsg);
```

Is there a way to chain .push()?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Oh... I'm just doing this in JQUERY... I guess it could be PHP... similar syntax..

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. I think you are confusing [JavaScript (a programming language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) and [jQuery (a JavaScript library)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Comment: **`push()` can't be chained, `concat()` can.** ...because `push()` simply returns new array length, not the array itself... - in theory, you could override it so it returns the array but I would strongly advice DON'T do that (other JS may rely on the documented return...)

@MattBall that makes a lot of sense actually e.g. you may want to do modifications AFTER you add some item or you want to just add an item but return the whole array (which is not chaining but requires same behavior)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chatCenterMembers.push(activeMembers,noactiveMsg,noactiveNomsg)
```

Comment: That will create an array of arrays, not one array of all the members of each array.

Comment: Rob... I've heard push() is faster then concat() is that true? if so can it be done with push?

Comment: Push would need to iterate over all the members of each array, so I doubt it would be faster. Probably more obvious to maintainers though.

Answer (score 37):

You're looking for the (vanilla) JavaScript method [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

> Returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s) and/or value(s).

Example, following your code:

```
chatCenterMembers = chatCenterMembers
    .concat(activeMembers)
    .concat(noactiveMsg)
    .concat(noactiveNomsg);
```

Comment: I would say this is exactly what the OP means.

Comment: I think for clarification it may have been nice to give an example of the array after it had been modified.

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite confusing. First of all, the question seems to be asking for a way to combine multiple arrays into one single array containing the elements of all the arrays. However, the accepted answer provides a solution for creating an array of arrays. Since the text in the question suggests merging the elements of multiple arrays into one array while the code example uses `push` with arrays as arguments, it's quite ambigious what the OP wants.

Furthermore, several answers have suggested using `concat`. While that fulfills the requirement of returning the resulting array after adding the provided element, and is fine for small sets of data and/or where performance and memory is not an issue, it's inefficient if dealing with large arrays, since each `concat` operation will allocate a new array, copy all the elements of the old array into it, then copy all the elements of the provided array into it, and dereference the old array (as opposed to simply adding elements to the same array object).

Consider calling `concat` `N` times, adding `C` elements each time:

```
allocate new array, copy C elements
allocate new array, copy 2 * C elements
allocate new array, copy 3 * C elements
...
```

A different approach would be to create your own method, either as a separate function or adding it to the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.append = function(e) {
    this.push(e);

    return this;
}
```

With this, you could do

```
[1, 2, 3].append(4).append(5).append(6)
```

without allocating more than one array object in total.

It could perhaps also be mentioned that with ES2015, the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator can be used to add all the elements of an array to another array using `push`:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6] 

arr1.push(...arr2); // arr1 is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This will however not fulfill the requirement of returning the resulting array for chaining, but the `append` method above could be used to merge multiple arrays like this:

```
chatCenterMembers = activeMembers.append(...noactiveMsg).append(...noactiveNomsg);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it instead with `.concat()`.

```
var chatCenterMembers=[];
chatCenterMembers = chatCenterMembers.concat(activeMembers, noactiveMsg, noactiveNomsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since on one else has posted it:

```
var chatCenterMembers = activeMembers.concat(noactiveMsg, noactiveNomsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

## push AND unshift chaining

I actually came here looking for both but didn't see any good answer so far for **unshift** so I'll note that here as well.

**push** chaining is straight forward

```
const list = ['hi', 'there']
  .concat(['buddy'])
// list is now ['hi', 'there', 'buddy']
```

but **unshift** chaining is weird

```
// need to use concat + map to do unshift chaining
const list = ['hi', 'there']
  .concat(['buddy'])
  .map((e, i, a) => i == 0 ? a[a.length - 1] : a[i-1])
// list is now ['buddy', 'hi', 'there']
```

As you can see using **map** there is a 3rd param given for the array you are using so this gives you power to do all sorts of odd things.

Comment: We can now use the `Array.prototpye.toSliced()` method to add/remove items with chaining.